# K3 surface is not the blow up of any other smooth surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, blowup, k3-surfaces

This is the exercise 2.5.5 in the book 'Complex Geometry' by Huybrechts:

Let $X$ be a K3 surface, i.e. $X$ is a compact complex surface with $K_X\cong\mathscr{O}_X$ and $h^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)=0$. Show that $X$ is not the blow-up of any other smooth surface.

Here $\dim X=2$, so if $X=\mathrm{Bl}_{\ell}S$ where $\dim\ell=1$ in $S$, then $X=S$. So we just need to consider the case $X=\mathrm{Bl}_{x}S$ where $x$ is a point of $S$. In this case $X=\mathrm{Bl}_{x}S\cong S\#\bar{\mathbb{P}^2}$. Now we have $\mathscr{O}_X=K_X\cong\sigma^*K_S\otimes\mathscr{O}_X(E)$ where $E$ is the exceptional divisor of the blow-up $\sigma:X\to S$. I tried to show that $\sigma^*K_S\otimes\mathscr{O}_X(E)$ must has a non-trivial global section, but I can't. Moreover, I don't know how to use $h^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)=0$.

Actually, I guess in this case $h^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ means $H^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ since in this book $h^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)=\dim H^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I found that in complex algebraic surfaces by Beauville, the exceptional surve $E$ should satisfies $E^2=-1$, but on K3 surface $C^2=2g-2$. So well done. But I not learned about this.

Comment: The idea is to somehow relate $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)$ to the topology of $X$. Blowing up a smooth point increases the rank of $H^1(X,\mathbb C)$, but this vanishes for a K3 surface (can you show this with the tools you have at hand?).

Comment: @DiamondVillager The comment in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348375/k3-surface-is-not-the-blow-up-of-any-other-smooth-complex-surface, you can show that this is a non trivial global section of $\sigma^*K_S\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(E)$, but $\mathcal{O}_X$ has only trivial section.

Comment: @AmiraLo Thank you! I have known this, but I don’t know how to prove that have non-trivial global section.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your help! I will think about this!

Comment: @DiamondVillager By $X\backslash E \cong S\backslash x$, $K_{X\backslash E}\cong K_{S\backslash x}$, then $K_{S\backslash x }\cong \mathcal{O}_{X\backslash E} \cong \mathcal{O}_{S \backslash  x} \Rightarrow K_S = \mathcal{O}_S$ only have trivial section. And $\mathcal{O}_X(E)$ has a non trivial section vanishing  along $E$, therefore $\sigma^*K_S\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(E)$ has nontrivial section.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!